# Extensão vscode para mostrar erros

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Qual a extensão eu uso para mostrar erro de códigos c# ? Exemplo estou usando a linha de código `Console.Write($"{_Nome} está passando \n");` sem importar o `using System` para que o console.write funcione, porem não está mostrando o risco vermelho em baixo da palavra console para me indicar que falta fazer a importaçao da biblioteca, alguem sabe me dizer qual seria essa extensão ?

Answer (score 0):

amigo, tenta usar essa aqui tem sido muito útil pra mim, em alguns momentos talvez tu precise executar o projeto(vai mostrar o erro e parar a execução) pra ele mostrar o "risco vermelho".

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: estou usando essa ai já e não está mostrando o erro, nao sei o pq...